# What is the name of this "cartesian-with-tuples-like" operation?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

Suppose the following combinatorial object:

Say we have three sets: {A1, A2}, {B1, B2}, {C1, C2}, for example's sake, in general - arbitrary number of sets and elements.
When we take one element from each, the set of all possible triplets is called Cartesian Product.

There is another possible scenario: create a set of 1 element AND 2 elemets AND 3 elements long, like this:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
...
A1, B1
A1, B2,
A1, C1
...
A1, B2, C1
A2, B2, C2
```

Is there a name for this operation and resulting set?

Answer (score 0):

It is often unreasonable to expect new "names" for niche constructions. But what you *can* usually (always?) do is to write a precise notation for the construction. There might be many ways to write the notation, some more concise, some less so.

Here's one way, perhaps not optimized for conciseness, but nonetheless quite precise.

First, choose notations  your three sets
$$S_1 = \{A_1,A_2\} \qquad S_2 = \{B_1,B_2\} \qquad S_3=\{C_1,C_2\}
$$
Then the set you are asking about can be denoted:
$$S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_2 \cup (S_1 \times S_2) \cup (S_1 \times S_3) \cup (S_2 \times S_3) \cup (S_1 \times S_2 \times S_3)
$$

Comment: Thank you! The main reason why I wanted to know a name is because I want to know how many combinations I get from this operation. Could you please suggest how I can calculate this?

Comment: That could make a good followup question. But perhaps this notation gives you enough of a clue to work the answer out for yourself (count how many elements there are in each of the 7 terms of that union, and add them all up).

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but the resulting formula for 3  sets seems to be:
$$
\left| S_{1}+1 \right|\times \left| S_{2}+1 \right|\times\left| S_{3}+1 \right| - 1
$$
And the formula for the arbitrary number of sets will be something like this.
$$
\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{n}\left| S_{i}+1 \right|\right) - 1
$$

Comment: This does not answer the question, what this construction is called.

Comment: Yeah, it answers the follow up question (I can't leave comments yet). My answer to the original question would be the same as Lee's: there's no such conventional name.